# Flutter: Write _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> to Rx<TestModel>

Tags: flutter, dart

I am practicing Modeling in Flutter. I have successfully write the model to GetStorage. And, I want to update the model from GetStorage value.

test_model.dart

```
class TestModel {
  String name;
  String city;
  // List<Huh> huh;

  TestModel(
    this.name,
    this.city,
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> testModel = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    testModel['name'] = this.name;
    testModel['city'] = this.city;
    return testModel;
  }
}
```

Testing.dart

```
Rx<TestModel> testModel = TestModel('', '').obs;
test() {
   testModel().name = 'ellen';
   testModel().city = 'Tokyo';
   GetStorage().write('user_test', testModel());
}
```

GetStorage() returns `{name: ellen, city: Tokyo}`.

Type of GetStorage().read('user_test') is `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` and testModel is `Rx<TestMode>`.

I am trying to retrieve data from GetStorage and write it to TestModel. I am getting

`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'TestModel' in type cast`

Tried to use `parseJson` or `Map<>.from`, however, I haven't quite figured it out yet.

Comment: What is the code for GetStorage()?  There's a type mismatch there.

Comment: GetStorage() is the GetX package. I assumed that there is a mismatch in types. I am trying to convert that `Map<String, dynamic>` to `Rx<TestMode>`. But, kinda stuck trying things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
factory TestModel.fromMap(Map data) {
  return TestModel(
    name: data['name'],
    city: data['city'],
  );
}
```

Then, pass GetStorage().read into the fromMap method.

```
TestModel.fromMap(GetStorage().read('user_test'));
```

Comment: I have just one question. `TestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` and ` Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {}` are executed without any command? I don't see any execute command line for either `fromJson` and `toJson`. But then, it just works.

Comment: They are constructor methods.  They activate when you call them.  They are pretty handy.